# React Native Upload to IOS Deployment Error Correct Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, deployment

I have submitted my app to the app store a couple times already using archive and then submit over the past couple months.  Unfortunately I am running into this error now.  I am thinking it has something to do with certificate or profile showing none, but am not sure what I need to be changing since I literally didn't change anything.  I have the correct bundle identifier and haven't changed that.  I did try to upgrade to react native .60 and then went back to .59 and am wondering if somehow that screwed something up or what I need to do to correct this issue.

[image: ca]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get around this issue using application loader (which I have never used before), but I exported the archive and uploaded it there and had no issues.  This indicates an expo issue which is weird since I didn't update anything, but for anyone else facing this issue with an app already created I would try this approach.